# Pandas difference between columns of different categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

I have a dataframe with 1000 columns that looks like this

```
Item Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value..n
A      12     24     14    50     43
B      14     27     13    48     47
C      10     32     17    89     49
D      17     30     15    23     40
```

I want to calculate the difference between the values based on the Item variable, something like this

```
Difference Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value..n
A-B          2      3      1      2      4
A-C          2     ...    ......    ...
A-D
B-C
B-D
C-D
```

and exclude the rows where if an item has more entries than the others. For example of item A has 100 entries and item B has 150, then the difference would be calculated of the first 100 entries and the next 50 entries of item B would be excluded from calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `itertools.combinations`, then `reindex` and create the dataframe

```
import itertools
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([*itertools.combinations(df.Item,2)])
df = df.set_index('Item')

out = pd.DataFrame(df.reindex(idx.get_level_values(0)).values-df.reindex(idx.get_level_values(1)).values,
                   index=idx,
                   columns=df.columns)
out.index=out.index.map('-'.join)
out
     Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  Value
A-B      -2      -3       1       2     -4
A-C       2      -8      -3     -39     -6
A-D      -5      -6      -1      27      3
B-C       4      -5      -4     -41     -2
B-D      -3      -3      -2      25      7
C-D      -7       2       2      66      9
```

Comment: Something like `index=['-'.join(i) for i in idx]` in the DataFrame constructor would also work. Also `idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(itertools.combinations(df.Item, 2))` should work fine without needing to unpack into a list no?